EFK Stack - timestamp on Kibana dashboard is coming as 000
I am using EFK stack to see my aggregated logs. When I see kibana dashboard, all timestamps are coming in format May 7, 2024 @ 16:59:21.000. I would like to bring you notice to 000. This is coming for all the records. Can anyone please help in solving the puzzle?
elasticsearch:8.2.2
kibana:8.2.2
My FluentD config is:
# fluentd/conf/fluent.conf

<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match api.log>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    scheme https
    ssl_verify false
    ca_file SSL_CERT_FILE
    user elastic
    password elastic
    logstash_format true
    validate_client_version true
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>

<match Loopback>
  @type copy

  <store>
    @type elasticsearch
    host elasticsearch
    port 9200
    scheme https
    ssl_verify false
    ca_file SSL_CERT_FILE
    user elastic
    password elastic
    logstash_format true
    validate_client_version true
  </store>

  <store>
    @type stdout
  </store>
</match>

<match *.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

Logger File:
      const logger = createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    // format: format.simple(),
    format: format.combine(
      // debugFormat, // uncomment to see the internal log structure
      format.timestamp({ format: timezoned }),
      format.simple(),
      logFormat
      // logLikeFormat,
      // debugFormat, // uncomment to see the internal log structure
    ),
    exitOnError: false,
    defaultMeta: { service: 'BillHive-facade' },
    transports: [
        // new transports.File(winstonTransportConfigFactory("file")),
        // new transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
        fluent,
        new transports.Console()
    ]
});

const logFormat = format.printf(info => {
  const formattedDate = info.timestamp.replace('T', ' ').replace('Z', '');
  return `${formattedDate} | ${info.level}| ${
   info.message
  };`;
 });


I solved it by changing timezoned function from statement format.timestamp({ format: timezoned }) . if anyone needs more details, please comment and I will share the code
